# Handling the Enter Key with IF Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a simple ASP.NET C# app that uses a USB barcode scanner. I have a Details View that defaults to Insert with a Submit Button at the bottom. When the page loads, the form grabs the ID from the URL and inputs that to the first field, it then sets the cursor focus to the 2nd field.

The USB scanner enters the number it scans followed by the Enter Key by default. I'd like to put a handler in there that basically says something like:

- If cursor is in textbox2 and Enter Key is pressed, keep the data in
  textbox2 and move cursor to textbox3.
- If cursor is in textbox3 and Enter Key is pressed, keep the data in
  textbox3 and hit the submit button.

The idea is that the user can scan 3 or 4 barcodes in a row filling in each textbox in the form without A) the submit button being triggered each time, and B) not having to click in each field prior to scanning (if I disabled the Enter Key).

Here is the start of my code, which grabs the ID from the URL and fills textbox1, then sets the focus to textbox2.

```
protected void DetailsView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DetailsView1.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Insert)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
            {
                    TextBox tbox1 = DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
                    TextBox tbox2 = DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox2") as TextBox;
                    if (tbox != null)
                    {
                        tbox.Text = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
                    }
                    SetFocus(tbox2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When done with `textbox1` couldn't you just check to see which control currently has focus and set it then?  For example, if `tbox2` has focus, `SetFocus(tbox3)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But i think that the enter flow already works doesn't it?
Why don't you add a flow for the textbox only with JQuery?

```
$('#TextBox1').keydown(function(e) {
   var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which); // Crossbrowser fix
   if(code === 13) {          //If Enter keycode
     $('#TextBox2').focus(); // Set focus to second textbox
     e.preventDefault();     // Prevent that the enter does a submit
   }
});
```

If the enter flow doesn't work, you can configure this for the form.

Comment: In my case, textbox2 is followed by textbox3. When I scan the barcode, textbox2 is filled with data, the enter key is pressed and the form gets submitted. It skips textbox3 all together.

Comment: Remember that the names only are for example, and that you can use this example also for Textbox2 and Textbox3 .. The e.preventDefault should prevent that the keydown of enter will execute and will set the focus to the named textbox that you provided. For this to work you need to think that Textbox1 in my example is Textbox2 and textbox2 is Textbox3. But names you can edit yourself.

Comment: I understand the name change, I guess I'm confused on where this goes in the code. Doing some Google Fu but if you know off the top of your head that would be much appreciated. Very much a noobie on jQuery.

Comment: In your aspx page you need to add the following line in the head tag to download Jquery. 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
Then you post the code which i posted above within <script>$(document).ready(function(){

   // jQuery methods go here...

});
</script> tags in the head below the script line for Jquery. tomorrow i answer if you have more questions..

Comment: Hi Spons. Thanks again for all your help. Do I need to call the function from the Details view? Or by just placing the code in the header will it happen automatically? Still not acting as expected. Visual Studio isnt catching any errors in the code.

Comment: Thank you. Just flipped you an email.